# Setting Angular variable to html "name"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have a object that is passed back.The object is a bunch of survey questions, with option to enter response.  This object has a variable called "Mandatory" meaning that this questions is mandatory.

So we can display the questions and also pass back answers ("o.Answertext"). But I am struggling to set up the mandatory field validation.

```
<div ng-if="o.QuestionType == 'Text'">
    <textarea class="form-control" ng-model="o.AnswerText"
            name="{{o.SurveyQuestionId}}" rows="5" id="comment"></textarea>
    <br />
    <div ng-if="o.Mandatory == true">
        <span style="color:red" ng-if="form.$submitted || form.o.SurveyQuestionId.$touched"
                ng-show="form.o.SurveyQuestionId.$error.required">
            Required
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can see that  `ng-if="o.Mandatory == true` becomes activated. But my span `ng-if` never becomes activated.

Comment: Log the value of `$scope.o.QuestionType` to debug.

Comment: You'll need to use square bracket notation due to the dynamic element name, ie `form[o.SurveyQuestionId].$touched`, `form[o.SurveyQuestionId].$error.required`, etc

Comment: The issue is making the ng-if in the span active. I need that to confirm validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/bororififu/1/edit?html,js,output) 
Use `ng-required` in your `<textarea>`

```
<form name='mainForm'>
 <div ng-if="o.QuestionType == 'Text'">
    <textarea class="form-control" ng-required='o.Mandatory'
           name='{{o.SurveyQuestionId}}' ng-model="o.AnswerText" rows="5" id="comment"></textarea>
    <br />
    <div style='color: red' ng-if="mainForm[o.SurveyQuestionId].$touched &&  mainForm[o.SurveyQuestionId].$error.required">
            Required
        </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

here's the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/textarea)

Comment: See my comment above about the form element name. It's not literally `SurveyQuestionId`

Comment: @Phil I edited my answer, I think it's correct now :)

Comment: got this working by instead of adding `required=''` instead of 'ng-required' thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @test, no problem. Hmmm, Based on what you've done with `required=''` have you tried setting `o.Mandatory = false` and still got the correct result?